# DB2: Insert Query

Tags: insert, db2, multiple-insert

There is table from which I need to select some data based on date criteria which I can do after that need to insert the same data in the same table with the value of one of the columns which is also a key field needs to be changed before insertion.

The Columns of the table are like:

1st key, 2nd key, 3rd key, 4th column,.....26th column, row_update_time, last_upd_user_id, row_create_tm_, row_create_usid.

Now I need to retrieve the data which were updated after a certain date and then insert the same data in this table with a different 2nd key and row_update_time as current time.

I am able to select all the data based on the date criteria and it is retrieving nearly 300 rows. How can I insert with modification in a single shot?

Can any one please help me in this.?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the structure of your table? You need to add as much information as possible so that people here could help you better..

Answer (score 1):

Your question is *very* vague, but something like this might be what you are looking for:

```
insert into the_table (id, some_column, other_column)
select id * 2, some_column, 'foobar'
from the_table
where id = 1;
```

If this is not what you are looking for you need to be a ***lot*** more specific (e.g. with examples of your table structure and data).